# USDC is not working properly with Web3JS on Binance Smart Chain

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, binance, binance-smart-chain

We can't fetch USDC transaction receipts using with Web3JS on Binance Smart Chain.

This is working on Ethereum and Polygon using USDT, DAI, SLP.

```
// We're using https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org as the RPC
const web3 = Web3Manager.load(transaction.blockchain);
console.log(transaction.transactionHash);

// Sample Transaction Hash: 0x9432e517b3cb5157525c935df88d10843f61b3cd6e278505e825bead0d0759e0
const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction.transactionHash);
console.log(receipt);
```

This code returns

```
0x9432e517b3cb5157525c935df88d10843f61b3cd6e278505e825bead0d0759e0
null
```

Comment: From which NPM package (or URL) do you import the `Web3Manager`?

Answer (score 0):

I can validate this error happens with Binance Smart Chain, actually, I require the receipt event but it never gets fired

```
contract.methods.myMethod(arg1, arg2)
 .send({ from, nonce, gas, gasPrice, value: 0 })
 .on('receipt', (receipt: any) => {...}) // Never gets fired
```

I had to use a polling method for that checking every minute the txHash with

```
const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
```